# Printing from Joomla using the print icon

Tags: joomla

Can anyone help me understand what is happening when I try to print from a joomla site:

When I use the print icon I get the expected result of just printing the article (ie no headers, side modules etc) but I also lose all the default.css that is used for my template.  ie no type styling and only see the style that has been included inline in the article. The result is pretty grim as the text size is all wrong.

However, if I try to print directly from the browser I keep the format applied from the default.css of my template but do not see any of the images that are included in JCE ImageManager PopsUps- presumeably because the browser is blocking pop-ups.

Can anyone explain what I need to add to a print.css and how joomla knows to use this when printing using the print icon.
Many thanks in anticipation of a reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can identify a print stylesheet by doing something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```

I am not sure though if joomla can identify it by this. On Joomla do it like this:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet( 'http://www.example.com/css/mystylesheet.css', 'text/css', 'print' );
```

Have a look here: http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addStyleSheet on the Joomla part. Maybe this is sufficient, but it may also depend on the version